# Do JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() change data type?

Tags: javascript, json

I need a little bit of help to understand JSON better.

When I stringify an array with class objects then parse it back, it looks like the array loses the class instance. Can I keep the class even after parse JSON data, and if can, how? And why does this happen?

Here is the code:

```
class Account {
    constructor(site, login, pass) {
        this.site = site,
        this.login = login
        this.pass = pass
    }
}
const accounts = [
    new Account("website1.com", "email1@gmail.com", "12345"),
    new Account("website2.com", "email2@gmail.com", "23456")
]
console.log('BEFORE', accounts)


const string = JSON.stringify(accounts)
console.log(string)


const parseString = JSON.parse(string)
console.log('AFTER', parseString)
```

The console shows like this:

```
BEFORE (2) [Account, Account]
{string: "[{"site":"website1.com","login":"email1@gmail.com"….com","login":"email2@gmail.com","pass":"23456"}]"}
AFTER (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

To make things clear, is it possible to have `[Account, Account]` after JSON.parse()`?

Let me know if my explanation is not clear.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Pass in a custom [_reviver_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) parameter but be warned, it's not a particularly robust API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON has no support for types other than object, array, null, string, number and boolean.

If you kind of know what you can expect in your JSON, you can use a reviver function during parsing. For your example, this suffices:

```
JSON.parse(string, (k, v) => v.hasOwnProperty('site')
                             ? new Account(v.site, v.login, v.pass)
                             : v);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has two useful methods to deal with JSON-formatted content: 
JSON.stringify() & JSON.parse(), which are useful to learn as a pair.
JSON.stringify() takes a JavaScript object and then transforms it into a JSON string.
JSON.parse() takes a JSON string and then transforms it into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that, you want your parsed JSON String converted into your Account Object Prototype. To achieve you could use the below code since JSON.parse() returns Javascript object which we explicitly need to convert to our custom object prototype ( i.e. Account in your case).

```
const string = JSON.stringify(accounts)
console.log(string);

const parseString = JSON.parse(string);

objectFromJson = function (parseString){
    var temp = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < parseString.length; i++) {
       temp.push(new Account (parseString[i].site, parseString[i].login, parseString[i].pass));
    }
    return temp;
};

var accountArray = objectFromJson(parseString);
console.log('AFTER', accountArray);
```